# Terminator 1.91 slow after few days

Tags: terminator

I am using terminator 1.91; and it tends to get very slow over time. By slow I mean the interactive response & display. I generally have very very long sessions for multiple days with approximately 20 tabs open; not using any grouping functionality. Also, not displaying a lot of data continuously in any terminal.

The bug happens in 1.91 and the current head release but doesn't happen on 0.98 though I can't use 0.98 because of another unrelated bug. I have also tried to completely remove my config file and that doesn't help either.

## Library Calls in 5 seconds (time ltrace -c -f -p 24070)

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 20.66    0.110916         135       818 strlen
 19.03    0.102159         135       752 memset
 13.44    0.072136         135       532 memcmp
 11.12    0.059714         136       438 strchr
 10.45    0.056124         136       412 __ctype_b_loc
  6.45    0.034630         137       252 strncpy
  4.94    0.026512         132       200 memcpy
  3.12    0.016724         135       123 sem_post
  2.42    0.012983         141        92 pthread_self
  2.18    0.011700         139        84 malloc
  2.13    0.011434         136        84 sem_trywait
  2.10    0.011292         134        84 free
  1.13    0.006068         155        39 sem_wait
  0.71    0.003818         159        24 __errno_location
  0.12    0.000650         325         2 strcmp
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.536860                  3936 total
0.14user 0.49system 0:05.44elapsed 11%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2888maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+222minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

## System calls in 5 seconds (time strace -c -f -p 24070)

```
strace: Process 24070 attached with 4 threads
^Cstrace: Process 24070 detached
strace: Process 24072 detached
strace: Process 24073 detached
strace: Process 24074 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 80.09    0.023601         142       166           poll
  9.46    0.002787        2787         1           restart_syscall
  4.38    0.001292           4       302       191 read
  3.25    0.000957           5       190       163 recvmsg
  2.40    0.000707           4       188           write
  0.14    0.000042          11         4           sendmsg
  0.14    0.000041           3        13           writev
  0.14    0.000041           3        16           nanosleep
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.029468                   880       354 total
0.00user 0.04system 0:05.36elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2464maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+162minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

## lsof shows a lot of /tmp/#<> files and a few /dev/pmtx

It would be great if anybody has any idea.

Comment: If you're having performance trouble with a piece of software as an end user of that software, the author thereof would typically be the right point of recourse. BTW, unless this happens *only* when running bash inside that terminal, I would generally not consider it a candidate for the tag.

Comment: Do you have unlimited scroll buffer? Maybe it's getting too large and starts swapping.